# Найти максимальный по модулю элемент матрицы

Tags: c#, массивы, матрицы

Не выводит отрицательные элементы, если они по модулю больше. С положительными вроде-бы все хорошо.

Пожалуйста, помогите понять, почему.

(Перед этим в коде ввод с консоли кол-ва столбцов и рядов матрицы и ее рандомное заполнение.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(matrix1[i, j]) > max_1)
                {
                    max_1 = matrix1[i, j];
                    max_i1 = i;
                    max_j1 = j;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Если вы в max_1 записываете отрицательное число, у вас условие на следующей итерации обязательно выполнится, т.к. модуль неотрицательный. Сравнивайте модули.

Comment: Кирилл Малышев, спасибо большое)